# PHP Force downloading produces corrupt files

Tags: php, html

First of all... I know this problem has been discussed many times before on this website and I've been reading the comments and solutions for the past hours, but nothing helped.

The code I'm posting here has been trimmed, but still includes the problem I'm facing.

I've created a small script to force a download using PHP. This is only a part of the code I'm trying to use on my website as I didn't want to spam you with too much irrelevant code, but it still includes the false output.

Everything in this code is tested with a .PNG file of 10.6KB

**NOTE:** The original question has been deleted since it had been solved. However, I came across another problem as I inplemented my code snippet into my website.

I created a function to download the file:

```
<?php
function download_file($file) 
{
    $known_mime_types=array(
        "htm" => "text/html",
        "exe" => "application/octet-stream",
        "zip" => "application/zip",
        "doc" => "application/msword",
        "jpg" => "image/jpg",
        "php" => "text/plain",
        "xls" => "application/vnd.ms-excel",
        "ppt" => "application/vnd.ms-powerpoint",
        "gif" => "image/gif",
        "pdf" => "application/pdf",
        "txt" => "text/plain",
        "html"=> "text/html",
        "png" => "image/png",
        "jpeg"=> "image/jpg"
    );  
    if(!is_readable($file)) die('<p class="error">File not found or inaccessible!</p>');

    $file_extension = strtolower(substr(strrchr($file,"."),1));
    if(array_key_exists($file_extension, $known_mime_types)){
        $mime_type=$known_mime_types[$file_extension];
    } else {
        $mime_type="application/force-download";
    };

    $fsize = filesize($file);

    header('Content-Type: ' .$mime_type);
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.basename($file).'"');
    header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
    header('Content-Length: '.$fsize);
    header('Accept-Ranges: bytes');
    header('Connection: Keep-Alive');
    header('Expires: 0');
    header('Pragma: public');
    header('Cache-Control:');
    readfile($file);
    exit();
}
?>
```

The download.php from which I call the function :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<?php
require_once 'connect.inc.php';
require_once 'core.inc.php';
require_once 'download_file.php';
?>
<html>
<head>
    <title>x3d Download</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css" type="text/css"/>  
    <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<?php
if (loggedin())
{
    include_once 'navbar_loggedin.php';
}
else 
{
    include_once 'navbar_loggedout.php';
}
?>
<div class="container" width="900px">
    <h2>Downloads</h2>
<?php
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM `files`";
    $result = mysql_query($sql);
    if (!$result)
    {
        echo '<p>No downloads available.</p>';
    }
    else 
    {
        echo '<table class="table table-hover"><tr>';
        echo '<tr><th>Filename</th>';
        echo '<th>Filetype</th>';
        echo '<th></th>';
        if (loggedin())
        {
            if (getuserlevel($_SESSION['user_id']) == 'Administrator')
            {
                echo '<th></th>';
            }
        }
        while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) 
        {
            echo '<tr><td><p>'.$row['file_name'].'</p></td>';
            echo '<td><p>'.$row['file_type'].'</p></td>';
            echo '<td><a href="download.php?download='.$row['file_id'].'"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-download-alt" aria-hidden="true"></span></a></td>';
            if (loggedin())
            {
                if (getuserlevel($_SESSION['user_id']) == 'Administrator')
                {
                    echo '<td><a class="red" href="download.php?delete='.$row['file_id'].'"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove" aria-hidden="true"></span></a></td>';
                }
            }
        } 
        echo '</tr></table>';
    }
?>
<?php
if (isset($_GET['download'])) 
{
    $sql = "SELECT `file_name` FROM `files` WHERE `file_id`='".$_GET['download']."'";
    if ($result = mysql_query($sql)) 
    {
        $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
        $file = "uploads/" . $row['file_name'];
        download_file($file);
    }
}

if (isset($_GET['delete'])) 
{
    $sql = "SELECT `file_name` FROM `files` WHERE `file_id`='".$_GET['delete']."'";
    if ($result = mysql_query($sql)) 
    {
        $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
    }

    if ($row['file_name'] == "")
    {
        echo '<p class="error">File does not exist.</p>';
    }
    else
    {
    $filepath = "uploads/".$row['file_name'];
    $sql = "DELETE FROM `files` WHERE `file_id`='".$_GET['delete']."'";
    if (file_exists($filepath)) 
    {
        try
        {
            if (unlink($filepath))
            {
                if ($result = mysql_query($sql))
                {
                    header('Location: download.php');
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception $e)
        {
            echo '<p class="error">Could not delete file.</p>';
        }
    }
    }
}
?>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

The code to call the function has been tested and my sql queries do return the correct value.

The image contains a part of my html source code and the original image...

Can anyone help me out?

Comment: What is a "failed download session"? Any specific errors the browser might have output? Like "Failed to download due to X"

Comment: @Alan Machado The browser error comes in two forms, depending on what file extension I'm using. 
1) C:\Users\XX\AppData\Local\Temp\XX.png.part could not be saved, because the source file cannot be read. 
2) This error isn't given, but Firefox simply says the download failed.

Comment: I have little experience in download/upload issues, but sounds like the problem you have when the server doesn't allow resuming suspended downloads (even when you don't, but the download manager [in that case the browser itself] split the file in parts to fetch it). You defined `Accept-Ranges: bytes;` but not `Content-Range: bytes=12345-`, could that be a cause? (Referred from [here](http://serverfault.com/questions/484091/enable-disable-resuming-downloads-feature-on-the-server-side))

Comment: If your first piece of code produces a file of 140 bytes, have you tried opening it up in a text editor? That filesize suggests to me that you're getting an error message that might point you in the right direction.

Comment: @andrewsi I have openend it with Notepad++ and it contained a piece of the original image accompanied with my html source code.

Comment: can you try with `$file = __DIR__."/uploads/" . $row['file_name'];`?

Comment: @Federico Still same problem.. I'm testing on my localhost, so I'm pretty sure it has nothing to do with the directory.

Comment: It's hard to tell where the problem. If your `$file`'s path is correct, then it should work. Can you post an example of `$file`? How are organized your directory? Can you post all the contents of the file with the `download_file` function? Maybe you should open another question!

Comment: @Federico Maybe you also want to see the problem for yourself? I've uploaded my website to a free webhost.
http://x3dnet.herobo.com/download.php

Comment: Can you post your `download.php`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/92301/discussion-between-shwasted-and-federico).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code is good. But what you are downloading is a fatal error, not the image:

```
<br />
<b>Fatal error</b>:  Call to undefined function fileread() in <b>/var/www/html/test.php</b> on line <b>18</b><br />
```

Change `fileread($file);` with `readfile($file);`, and it should work.

Next time you have a "corrupt file of 140 bytes", try to open it as a text file.

Comment: Good call, I've missed it was 'reversed' :)

Comment: This is a huge facepalm >.< Thank you very much! It does solve the problem in my code, now I'll try to implement it in the rest of my code, but I'm confident it'll work.

Comment: I still have got corrupted files when I try to call this snippet of code by using a function...

Comment: @Frederico All sorts of files, but I'm currently still testing with images. I've opened the corrupted file with Notepad++ and it contains my html source code and the image. (Should I update this question and post my new code?)

Comment: @Federico Question has been updated, hope you can help me out.